# Angularjs send search filter data with $http

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ui-grid

We are using ui-grid. We want to search grid with many of its columns. So it is bit of awkward to send all the filter criteria on url as routeparams. 
Is it OK to make search web api request with $http.post? Or any other solutions?

Comment: Yes its OK to use POST method. Or with GET method you can pass as QueryString. It doesnt't matter if user knows parameter.

Comment: You could send a json object as one paramter in a GET request. Stringify the object before send and parse it when recieving it server side. That way you only have one parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You could send a json object as one paramter in a GET request. Stringify the object before send and parse it when recieving it server side. That way you only have one parameter. – Marcus H

Thanks Marcus H